# Removing date characters from a SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, join

I want the join clause to look at the first part of a time stamp, without removing anything from the actual table.

Currently the date looks like this 'Year-Month-Day Hour-Minute-Second-Nanosecond'. I want to just match the 'Year-Month-Day' and ignore the rest. Because the first part is always 10 characters is it possible to do a like statement that will just look at the first ten.

```
SELECT *
FROM t_logs_SigDocQueued
INNER JOIN t_log_Task ON t_logs_SigDocQueued.MedicalRecordNumber = t_log_Task.PermanentIdentifier and t_logs_SigDocQueued.ActionDate = t_log_Task.Received
LEFT JOIN t_log_Tasks ON t_log_Task.DocumentID = t_log_Tasks.DocumentID
```

The problem with what I have now is that the dates could be nanoseconds apart and so the entire return is null.

Comment: This is exactly why joining by dates is a bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using convert function.

See below is your modified query with convert function.

```
SELECT *
FROM t_logs_SigDocQueued
INNER JOIN t_log_Task ON t_logs_SigDocQueued.MedicalRecordNumber = t_log_Task.PermanentIdentifier and 
convert(varchar, t_logs_SigDocQueued.ActionDate, 111) = convert(varchar, t_log_Task.Received, 111)
LEFT JOIN t_log_Tasks ON t_log_Task.DocumentID = t_log_Tasks.DocumentID
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I just didn't know about convert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the convert function to remove everything but the date:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM t_logs_SigDocQueued
    INNER JOIN t_log_Task ON t_logs_SigDocQueued.MedicalRecordNumber = t_log_Task.PermanentIdentifier and 
coNvert(varchar(12),t_logs_SigDocQueued.ActionDate,102) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),t_log_Task.Received,102)
    LEFT JOIN t_log_Tasks ON t_log_Task.DocumentID = t_log_Tasks.DocumentID
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods for this,

**- Method-1**

```
  SELECT *
    FROM t_logs_SigDocQueued
    INNER JOIN t_log_Task ON t_logs_SigDocQueued.MedicalRecordNumber = t_log_Task.PermanentIdentifier 
    and convert(varchar(10),t_logs_SigDocQueued.ActionDate,103) = convert(varchar(10),t_log_Task.Received,103)
    LEFT JOIN t_log_Tasks ON t_log_Task.DocumentID = t_log_Tasks.DocumentID
```

**- Method-2**

```
SELECT *
FROM t_logs_SigDocQueued
INNER JOIN t_log_Task ON t_logs_SigDocQueued.MedicalRecordNumber = t_log_Task.PermanentIdentifier 
and cast(t_logs_SigDocQueued.ActionDate as date) = cast(t_log_Task.Received as date)
LEFT JOIN t_log_Tasks ON t_log_Task.DocumentID = t_log_Tasks.DocumentID
```